# How to use different pointer arithmetic semantics

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, pointer-arithmetic

For academic purposes, I'm trying to purposefully overwrite data allocated on the free store. Here's what I've got working so far:

```
//main
int* val = new int(-1);

print_bits(*val);

short* i = new(val) short(0);
print_bits(*val);

std::cout << "\nval loc: " << val <<
             "\ni loc: " << i << std::endl;

delete val;
//end main
```

As expected, this produces something similar to:

```
11111111111111111111111111111111
00000000000000001111111111111111

val loc: 0x27d5580
i loc: 0x27d5580
```

My next intention was to override the second byte in val, so I simply change short allocation to:

```
short* i = new(val+1) short(0);
```

However, after making this change, I got output similar something like:

```
11111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111

val loc: 0x27d5580
i loc: 0x27d5584
```

As you can see, the val+1 move the pointer a full sizeof(int) bytes forward rather than just one byte forward. I understand why this happens (and am thankful for it). However, if my intention was to move only a single byte forward in memory, how could I accomplish that?

**EDIT:**

One solution I've come up with is to do something like

```
char* ch = &val;
short i = new(ch+1) short(0);
```

I'm actually not entirely sure yet whether this will work, since char*'s have a habit of being interpreted as C-style strings.

**Solution:**

The simplest solution that has been given is to write

```
short* i = new(reinterpret_cast<char*>(val)+1) short(0);
```

Comment: Cast `val` to `char*` before adding.

Comment: @alain I posted that edit as you recommended it. Haha

Comment: How that `habit` is related? `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be equal to 1 and that the only way to address memory byte by byte.

Comment: @AldenB  It is a wrong solution. The memory must be aligned. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `short` won't be a single byte, and storing via one at a single byte offset potentially both violates alignment requirements and potentially stores to space beyond the length of the original allocation (depending on the size of `short` vs `int`).

To "move" by single bytes, you want to use a `char *` type. Simply:

```
 *(reinterpret_cast<char*>(val)+1) = 0;
```

... should work.

Answer (score 1):

Just write

```
short* i = new(( char * )val + sizeof( short )) short(0);
```

or

```
short* i = new(reinterpret_cast<char *>( val ) + sizeof( short )) short(0);
```

Comment: The solution I actually used was short* i = new(reinterpret_cast<char*>(val)+1) short(0);

Comment: @AldenB It is a wrong solution. The memory must be aligned for objects of the type short.

Comment: @AldenB Vlad is right that the alignment should (most likely if not definitely) technically be greater than a byte for `short`, and your solution likely invokes "undefined behaviour" i.e. it might appear to work, some of the time, but there is no guarantee. OTOH Vlad's solution also ignores your question in regards to overwriting the second _byte_. One possibility is to just store a byte value via the `char *` - there is no need for the `new` operator here.

Comment: @AldenB (in case it's not clear, a `short` is not a single byte).